# How to have jpeg images be read in from a folder and shown in rendered HTML file in R?

Tags: html, r, imagemagick, jpeg, purrr

I am reading in files from a folder using the following method:

```
require(magick)
require(purrr)

folder <- list.files("location/to/folder_directory", pattern = ".jpeg", full.names = T)
image_plots <- map(folder, image_read)
print(image_plots)
```

When I do this, I see that the images are being read in from the folder into the R markdown. But when I knit, in my HTML file, all I see is that the images are present but not the actual image displayed. I want the actual plot to show and not the message that the plot was read in. How can I do that.

Comment: What is your chunk header? Also, do you have a setup chunk at the top of your RMD file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution that worked for me.

```
require(knitr)

folder <- list.files("location/to/folder_directory", pattern = ".jpeg", full.names = T)
include_graphics(folder)
```